# How to get 'selected' option value in edit mode with modal codeigniter 4

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-4

I have modal with options, i want to edit it, the value goes back like in create function. what i want to ask is how to get the value i've selected in edit function?

Here my model:
..................................................................................................

```
public function find_all()
                {
                    return $this->db->table('tbl_barang')
                        ->orderBy('id_barang', 'ASC')
                        ->get()
                        ->getResultArray();
                }
    
     public function get_kategori()
            {
                return $this->db->table('tbl_kategori')
                    ->orderBy('id_kategori', 'ASC')
                    ->get()
                    ->getResultArray();
            }
        
        public function get_satuan()
            {
                return $this->db->table('tbl_satuan')
                    ->orderBy('id_satuan', 'ASC')
                    ->get()
                    ->getResultArray();
            }
            
            public function join_kategori_satuan()
                {
                    return $this->db->table('tbl_barang')
                        ->join('tbl_kategori', 'tbl_kategori.id_kategori=tbl_barang.id_kategori')
                        ->join('tbl_satuan', 'tbl_satuan.id_satuan=tbl_barang.id_satuan')
                        ->get()
                        ->getResultArray();
                }
            
            public function update_data($data)
                {
                    $this->db->table('tbl_barang')
                        ->where('id_barang', $data['id_barang'])
                        ->update($data);
                }
```

Here is my controller:
..................................................................................................

```
public function index()
        {
            $data = [
                'title' => 'Goods',
                'message'   => 'Goods Page ',
                'kategori' => $this->M_Category->get_kategori(),
                'satuan' => $this->M_Item_Unit->get_satuan(),
                'goods' => $this->M_Goods->find_all(),
                'join_kategori_satuan' => $this->M_Goods->join_kategori_satuan(),
            ];
            return view('content/goods/v_goods', $data);
        }
    
    public function edit_goods($id_barang)
        {
            if ($this->validate([
                'foto_barang' => [
                    'rules'         => 'max_size[foto_barang,1024]|is_image[foto_barang]|mime_in[foto_barang,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png]',
                    'errors'        => [
                        'max_size'  => 'Size max 1Mb!',
                        'is_image'  => 'File not image!',
                        'mime_in'   => 'File format must jpg/jpeg/png!',
                    ]
                ],
            ])) {
                $file = $this->request->getFile('foto_barang');
                if ($file->getError() == 4) {
                    $data = [
                        'select_field_id' => $this->M_Goods->select_field_id($id_barang),
                        'id_barang'      => $id_barang,
                        'id_kategori'   => $this->request->getVar('id_kategori'),
                        'id_satuan'     => $this->request->getVar('id_satuan'),
                        'nama_barang'   => $this->request->getVar('nama_barang'),
                        'merk_barang'   => $this->request->getVar('merk_barang'),
                        'stok_barang'   => $this->request->getVar('stok_barang'),
                    ];
                    $this->M_Goods->update_data($id_barang, $data);
                } else {
                    $fotoLama = $this->M_Goods->change_photo($id_barang);
                    if ($fotoLama['foto_barang'] != "") {
                        unlink('./goods_photo/' . $fotoLama['foto_barang']);
                    }
                    $nama_file = $file->getRandomName();
                    $data = [
                        'id_barang'      => $id_barang,
                        'id_kategori'   => $this->request->getVar('id_kategori'),
                        'id_satuan'     => $this->request->getVar('id_satuan'),
                        'nama_barang'   => $this->request->getVar('nama_barang'),
                        'merk_barang'   => $this->request->getVar('merk_barang'),
                        'stok_barang'   => $this->request->getVar('stok_barang'),
                        'foto_barang'    => $nama_file,
                    ];
                    $file->move('goods_photo/', $nama_file);
                    $this->M_Goods->update_data($data);
                }
                session()->setFlashdata('success-edit', 'Goods Successfully Edited');
                return redirect()->to('Goods');
            } else {
                session()->setFlashdata('errors', \Config\Services::validation()->getErrors());
                return redirect()->to(base_url('Goods'));
            }
        }
```

Here my view:
..................................................................................................

```
<?php foreach ($goods as $key => $value) { ?>
        <div class="modal fade" id="edit<?= $value['id_barang']; ?>">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Item</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
    
                    <?php echo form_open_multipart('Goods/edit_goods/' . $value['id_barang']) ?>
                    <?= csrf_field(); ?>
    
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">

                <!-- THIS MY PROBLEM -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Category Name</label>
                                    <select name="id_kategori" class="form-control" required>
                                        <option value="">-- Choose Category --</option>
                                        <?php foreach ($kategori as $key => $value) { ?>
                                            <option value="<?= $value['id_kategori'] ?>"> <?= $value['nama_kategori'] ?></option>
                                        <?php  } ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Item Unit Name</label>
                                    <select name="id_satuan" class="form-control" required>
                                        <option value="">-- Choose Item Unit --</option>
                                        <?php foreach ($satuan as $key => $value) { ?>
                                            <option value="<?= $value['id_satuan'] ?>"> <?= $value['nama_satuan'] ?></option>
                                        <?php  } ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                    <!-- /.THIS MY PROBLEM -->

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo form_close() ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }; ?>
```

..................................................................................................

Comment: in your view ``<?php foreach ($goods as $key => $value) { ?>``. What do you have in ``$goods``?

Answer (score -1):

do it with jquery or js

```
    $("#n").val('item');

$('.class').val('item');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 